# which h264 profile supported by dxva2 hardaware decoder

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, hardware-acceleration, dxva

I have code which decode live h264 camera stream and dispay. I have use ffmpeg dxvae decoder.

Problems : 
avcodec_send_packet return negative error code.

What I have Tried :

1. I have dump stream packet and save in h264 file. then **ffmpeg.exe
       -hwaccel dxva2 -threads 1 -i output.h264 -f null - -benchmark** command verify and it throws error 
       **Failed setup for format dxva2_vld: hwaccel initialisation returned error.**
2. I have found h264 file has baseline profile. does baseline profile
   not supported by dxva2 decoder?
3. I am able to play file with vlc player.

Also I had decode high profile h264 video using above command and its works fine.

please help to fix this. thanks in advance.

Comment: If vlc player is able to play the file, it doesn't mean it plays the file using hardware decoding. vlc fallbacks to software decoding on some h264 file. i encountered some h264  files like that, in general some old mp4. I could take a look at those files caracteristics to see why hardware decoding can't be used

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your GPU hardware capabalities. For example, here is NVidia capabilities (from june 2016 codec sdk) :

[image]

Also, for NVidia, if you check this link [Nvidia PureVideo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_PureVideo) , some widths can't be decode :

> Note that all Feature Set B hardware cannot decode H.264 for the following widths: 769-784, 849-864, 929-944, 1009-1024, 1793-1808, 1873-1888, 1953-1968, 2033-2048 pixels.